# rails 3 sending view_context to Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

I'm trying Prawn to generate pdf's, following [this RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn-revised?view=asciicast)

If I tried the next code, it works fine:

```
pdf = OrderPdf.new(@order)
```

But, if added "view_context"

```
pdf = OrderPdf.new(@order, view_context)
```

I got this error: "SyntaxError in xxxController#index"
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'

I tried put in my controller `helper_method :view_context` but the error still.

Enviroment: rails 3.2.5

My Controller:

```
  def show

@liquidacion = Liquidacion.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @liquidacion }
  format.pdf do
    pdf = LiquidacionPdf.new (@liquidacion, view_context)
    send_data pdf.render, filename: "liquidacion_#{@liquidacion.anio.to_s()+''+@liquidacion.mes.to_s().rjust(2,'0')+''+@liquidacion.numeroliquidacion.to_s()}", type: "application/pdf", disposition: "inline"
  end
end 
end
```

And my classPDF:

```
class LiquidacionPdf < Prawn::Document
def initialize(liquidacion, view)
    super(top_margin: 20, :page_layout => :landscape)
    @liquidacion = liquidacion
            @view = view
    numero_liqui
    nombre_usuario
    lineas_liqui
    total_liquidacion
    firmas
end
```

How I writte this?

Comment: Can you pst your initialize method in your OrderPdf Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initialize method should accept two parameters. I am guessing that you still only have one it.

Change your initialize method to the below

```
 def initialize(order, view)
   super(top_margin: 70)
   @order = order
   @view = view 
   order_number
   line_items
 end
```

EDIT

take off parenthesis or empty space

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.html # show.html.erb
 format.json { render json: @liquidacion }
 format.pdf do
 pdf = LiquidacionPdf.new @liquidacion, view_context
```

Comment: thats right...  my initialize method in my OrderPdf Class, looks like this; but I don't why I got that error "syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
        pdf = OrderPdf.new (@order, view_context)"

Comment: Can you post your controller code? Also, what does view_context equal?

Comment: I edited my post, adding the code for my controller and my class PDF.  I don't equal the view_context, I don't know how do it.

Comment: check edited answer, or you could have   pdf = LiquidacionPdf.new(@liquidacion, view_context)